# Showing more than '__str__' for a Django foreign key field

Tags: django, django-admin, foreign-keys

I've two simple Django model classes,

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class ParentModel(models.Model):
    small_text = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    big_text = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.small_text


class ChildModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s is my parent' % self.parent
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
import models

admin.site.register(models.ChildModel)
admin.site.register(models.ParentModel)
```

So the default view is you see the 'small_text' in a select element in the admin section.  What I'd love to be able to do is extend that so that there's another TextArea, or something else I can , underneath the select which changes as you choose a different Daddy.

I've looked into a few different ways to do this, but they all seem hella complicated for what with Django, I'd have thought should be an easy task.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think ModelAdmin forms is the way to go here

Comment: [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/twidi/django-ajax-select)

Comment: @Paulo Bu, any chance you can expand on that.  I've worked a good bit with ModelAdmin forms, but still can't see any way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @seaders regardless of your python version, Django tries to use unicode everywhere, and the docs and examples all reccomend `__unicode__` over `__str__`. I'm sorry if you don't find that helpful  but my *comment* (not answer) was intended to be a helpful aside, not a derisive attack.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not quite get what you are trying to do. Do you want to change the text in the select box options on the change/add child page?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to be able to change ChildModel's properties while viewing the ParentModel in the admin, you should look into using an [inline in the admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

If you're looking to have additional fields appear when viewing the index page in the admin for a model, then you'll want to add additional properties to the [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) property on the model's admin class.